# Tensorflow - Prediction output dependent on batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I implemented a Generative Adversarial Network in Tensorflow. During test time the generated images are quite good if I generate them using the same batch_size that I used during training (64); if I generate one image at a time the result is horrible.

The possible causes may be 2:

- Batch Normalization?
- Wrong usage of tf.shape to get the dynamic batch size

Here is my code:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import batch_norm

def conc(x, y):
    """Concatenate conditioning vector on feature map axis."""
    x_shapes = x.get_shape()
    y_shapes = y.get_shape()

    x0 = tf.shape(x)[0]
    x1 = x_shapes[1].value
    x2 = x_shapes[2].value
    y3 = y_shapes[3].value

    return tf.concat([x, y * tf.ones(shape=(x0,x1,x2,y3))], 3)

def batch_normal(input, scope="scope", reuse=False):
    return batch_norm(input, epsilon=1e-5, decay=0.9, scale=True, scope=scope, reuse=reuse, updates_collections=None)

def generator(z_var, y):

     y_dim = y.get_shape()[1].value

     z_var = tf.concat([z_var, y], 1)

     d1 = tf.layers.dense(z_var, 1024,
                     kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                     name='gen_fc1')

    d1 = tf.nn.relu(batch_normal(d1, scope='gen_bn1'))

    # add the second layer

    d1 = tf.concat([d1, y], 1)

    d2 = tf.layers.dense(d1, 7 * 7 * 128,
                     kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                     name='gen_fc2')

    d2 = tf.nn.relu(batch_normal(d2, scope='gen_bn2'))

    d2 = tf.reshape(d2, [-1, 7, 7, 128])
    y = tf.reshape(y, shape=[-1, 1, 1, y_dim])

    d2 = conc(d2, y)

    deconv1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(d2, 64, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                     kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                     name='gen_deconv1')

    d3 = tf.nn.relu(batch_normal(deconv1, scope='gen_bn3'))

    d3 = conc(d3, y)

    deconv2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(d3, 1, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                     kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                     name='gen_deconv2')

    return tf.nn.sigmoid(deconv2)
```

Comment: Did you ever find the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in Batch Normalization actually. Batch Normalization has two phases: training and testing (inference). On the training phase, Batch Normalization uses batch statistics (mean and standard deviation) for normalization, while on the testing phase it uses statistics collected from the hole dataset. This average statistics is collected using moving average during the training phase (that's where `decay` parameter is used).

To distinguish between these two phases, `layers.batch_norm` has parameter called `is_training` which should be set to `True` during training and to `False` on inference. The easiest way to do this is to use a `placeholder` with type `tf.bool`.

So you should do something like this:

```
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

# some code here

output = batch_norm(input,
                    epsilon=1e-5,
                    decay=0.9,
                    scale=True,
                    scope=scope,
                    reuse=reuse,
                    updates_collections=None,
                    is_training=is_training)
```

Then, while training:

```
feed_dict = {..., is_training: True, ...}
```

On inference:

```
feed_dict = {..., is_training: False, ...}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy, actually I used a placeholder during training (set to true for training and set to false for validation) and a constant=false during predictions. But what happens is that accuracy during predictions gets down to 20%  (even with the same batch size!) while on training/validation it was 99%

Comment: What is different between your training/test time? Are you using the same graph/session, or creating the new ones?

Comment: When the training is finished I save the model. At test time I use another session and restore the model

Answer (score 1):

You may have other bugs, but batch normalization is certainly a big issue here.

Batch normalization computes the mean and variance of all variables at each layer in order to do the normalization.  This is meant as a proxy for the real mean and variance of the variables, meaning the mean and variance estimated on the complete population instead of a subset (the mini-batch).  If your mini-batch is large enough the approximated mean and variance are close enough to the real ones, but if you have a single example in your mini-batch, the estimation of the mean and variance will clearly be catastrophic.

What is done to fix that is that after your training is done, you do compute the mean and variance of all model variables from some large subset on inputs (larger than a mini-batch).  You then (somehow) plug back those values in the batch normalization layers and turn off the computation of mean and variance from the mini-batch.  This is fairly non-trivial to do, but I assume whatever library you are using can deal with this.  If a library can't deal with this, it is fairly useless since the trained model could never be used (unless you also evaluate it on mini-batches as you did).

I found this [tutorial](http://ruishu.io/2016/12/27/batchnorm/) online after a quick search.  It might be deprecated and there might be better ones.